Why does Eulers Theorem not work in this case?
In my number theory textbook I am tasked with finding the value of $5^{30}\mod 62$. As the last section had been about Eulers Theorem which states that for any $a,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ where the $\gcd(a,n)=1$
$$a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\mod n$$
The first thing I check was therefore what $\phi(62)$ is, and as $\phi(62)=30$ and $\gcd(5,62)=1$, I got the result
$$5^{30}\equiv1\mod 62$$
However when I double checked my anwser with MatLab I recived the anwser
>>mod(5^(30),62) = 44

And now I don't whats wrong, is this an error with my MatLab code or an error with my Number Theory?

I'm not familiar enough with MatLab, but it probably can't handle large integers.

It's likely a numerical issue with Matlab. You can check easily that $5^{10}\equiv 5 \mod 62$ and hence $5^{30}\equiv 5^{3}\equiv 1 \mod 62$. Perhaps Matlab can check those middle steps for you.

use powermod(a,b,m) for $a^b \mod m$ https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.powermod.html

I assumed that if the numbers were too big MatLab would have returned NaN and by using powermod(5,30,62) I get the correct anwser of 1.

$5^{30} \equiv 1 \pmod{62}$ is correct. R = IntegerModRing(62); R(5^30) on Sage indeed returns 1.

If you don't want to deal with symbolic numbers, a quick way around is to compute mod(5^15,62) and check the result squared mod 62 etc.

You are correct in your theoretical reasoning. Note that
$$\log_2(5^{30}) = 30 \times\log_25 \approx 69.7.$$
You need at least 70 bits to represent this number; typical Matlab integer types are 8, 16, 32, and 64 bits long. Instead you should use symbolic numbers to get
x = sym(5)^30;
y = mod(x, 62)


Thank you for the explanation, I was unaware of the typical integer types and I though MatLab would inform me if it were too big, I see I was wrong to think so. I will do further research into big numbers and MatLab.

Definitely some sort of issue with your computer (or your input): $$5^{30}\equiv 1\pmod {62},$$ because, for instance,  $$5^3\equiv 125\equiv 1\pmod {62}.$$
Then $$5^{30}\equiv (5^3)^{10}\equiv 1^{10}\equiv 1\pmod {62}.$$

Nice, that's a very fool-proof way to see it.

In this case, $3$ is the order of $5\pmod {62}.$   Whenever you raise a group element to a power a multiple of its order,  you get $1.$  This is a little group/number theory lingo.  @Adayah
